# AWS Batch Job Stuck at Runnable State

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, aws-batch

I’m developing an AWS architecture to generate 3D objects from taken images of an asset.

I’m following [this](https://aws.amazon.com/tr/blogs/media/photogrammetry-reconstruction-with-3dflow-on-aws/) document, so my architecture/code/test content same as this document.

Long story short system work like this:

[image: architecture]

My problem is the job is stuck in a runnable state in AWS Batch.

What I tried so far:

- I tried to increase the compute environment vCPU.
- Tried to create a new computing environment with a higher than required vCPU for the job.
- Tried to re-trigger the job.
- Tried to clone the job.

I have no other idea why the issue is happening.

Comment: I take it you've gone through this link? https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/batch-job-stuck-runnable-status/